# How to implement pagination over a dynamic list of records

Tags: pagination

I have to implement pagination over a database of tickets in OPEN state with page size as 10 tickets using HTTP GET.  The database of tickets however is not static and there can tickets that switch to CLOSED state from OPEN and new tickets in OPEN state that can get added to the database while the pagination is under way

In the current scenario consider the following cases

1) There are 100 tickets in OPEN state. When pagination starts we return 10 tickets and 10 pages as the total required pages.  When the user navigates from page 1 to page 2 , assume that 50 more tickets in OPEN state are added. However these tickets don't occur within the first 10 pages and hence are never shown

2) There are 100 tickets in OPEN state. When pagination starts we return 10 tickets and 10 pages as the total required pages.  When the user navigates from page 1 to page 2 , assume that 10 tickets switched to CLOSED state. So these tickets on page 1 are incorrect now and should not be shown.

What is the best approach to have pagination over a list of records which are dynamic?